# AWS Services and Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, region

I am very new with AWS and wanted to clear my concept on AWS services. I have read that that AWS has plenty of services that can also be accessed through API. A service is basically a software program. Then why are services not available in all regions. If my customers are from India, I can buy the EC2 instance from Asia but why should I choose service from USA East. Again, why does AWS provide regions for End Points. They could have installed all the services in all their regions - assuming that they are only software programs and not hardware resources.

Comment: Most of the service *do* require hardware resources, at least they need to make sure enough hardware is available to run whatever service you are talking about. What service *are* you talking about? Using services / resources closer to your user improves latency. And depending on the legal situation you might *have* to make sure data does not leave the country / area (e.g. the EU) and that rules out provisioning resources outside of that area.

Comment: Some services such as IAM are global to ensure uniqueness, while other such as AppSync or Glue  are regional as per the task they perform. Different regions have different compliance standards for data storage & operational activities ,so all services are not provided in all the regions

Answer (score 1):

Latency is not a big problem for you, I think, you can choose the best price options for your sources. If latency big a problem, you must choose the region/zone near your target market. Better understanding [read this doc.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html)

Answer (score 1):

AWS Services operate on multiple levels and are all exposed through APIs.
Some services operate at a global scope (e.g. Identity and Access Management or Route53), most on a regional level (e.g. S3) and others somewhere between the region and availability zone (EC2, RDS, VPC...).

AWS uses the concept of a region for multiple purposes, one of the major drivers being **fault isolation**. Something breaking in Ireland (eu-west-1) shouldn't stop a service in Frankfurt (eu-central-1) from operating. **Latency** is another driver here. Since physics is involved, higher distances also increase the latency, which makes things like replication more tricky. **Data residency** and other **compliance** aspects are also a good reason to compartmentalize services.
Services being regional results in their endpoints being regional as well.

As to not every service being available in every region: Hardware availability is part of the reason, it doesn't make sense to have the more obscure hardware for niche use cases (think GroundStation, their satellite control service) in all regions. Aside from that, there are most likely some financial aspects involved as well, as global scale and complexity come at a cost and if demand isn't sufficient, it may not make sense to roll out a service everywhere.